# How do you programmatically move an object in 3D space?

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d

I'm really new to WPF 3D animation, and there's something I'm still struggling with.

I am building a 3D UI for an app that loads assemblies from disk. I can create a cube that represents each of the assemblies currently loaded. I would like to animate the loading process as follows:

1. Choose a random point in 3D space and set this as the cube's starting position.
2. Animate the cube moving from that random point to the origin (0,0,0). Of course this involves repositioning any cubes that have already "slid" into place.

Creating the random starting point is no problem. Repositioning any existing cubes to make room for the new one (in a non-animated way) is no problem. But I can't seem to find the right combination of procedures to animate the cube moving from the random starting point to the origin.

My (really basic) XAML looks like this (grid within a window):

```
<Grid Background="WhiteSmoke">        
    <Viewport3D Name="MainViewport" Height="500" Width="975">            
        <Viewport3D.Camera>
            <PerspectiveCamera x:Name="CubeCam" Position="0,0,35" LookDirection="-1,-1,-25 " UpDirection="0,1,0" FieldOfView="45" />
        </Viewport3D.Camera>
        <Viewport3D.Children>                
            <ModelVisual3D x:Name="Light">
                <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                    <Model3DGroup>
                        <DirectionalLight Color="White" Direction="10,-60,-125" />
                        <AmbientLight Color="#FF333333"/>
                    </Model3DGroup>                        
                </ModelVisual3D.Content>
            </ModelVisual3D>      
            <ModelVisual3D>                    
                <ModelVisual3D.Content>                        
                    <Model3DGroup x:Name="CubeGroup" />
                </ModelVisual3D.Content>                    
            </ModelVisual3D>                
        </Viewport3D.Children>
    </Viewport3D>
</Grid>`
```

I'm currently using the HelixToolkit, but unless I'm missing something I've found the documentation to be lacking.

The cubes I'm attempting to animate are CubeVisual3D objects from the HelixToolkit. I create the cubes in code and add them to the CubeGroup.

I've tried varios XXXAnimation objects, but I always run into the same problem: when it comes time to set the target property, none of the objects I'm trying to animate have a DependencyProperty I can hook into.

Just to reiterate, I have no problem adding these cubes to static (albeit calculated) positions in 3D space. What I can't seem to do is animate them into position.

I appreciate any advice!